# Powershell InvokeGlobal Parameter count mismatch

Tags: powershell

I installed PSFramework on my W2k12 server. However when I run an import-module PSFramework I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "InvokeGlobal" with "0" argument(s): "Parameter count mismatch."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\psframework\1.6.181\PSFramework.psm1:7348 char:2
+     $isInstalled = $provider.IsInstalledScript.InvokeGlobal()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TargetParameterCountException
```

This works fine on my Win 10 machine.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Comment: Have you installed WMF 5.1? IIRC PSFramework requires powershell 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of PSFramework, sorry about that fail!

One of my security-related feature updates broke PSv3 & PSv4 support, I didn't notice right away and then was drowned in heavy workload to fix it timely.

I've added an issue that you can track until it is resolved:
https://github.com/PowershellFrameworkCollective/psframework/issues/474

In the meantime, you can resolve this on your server by updating its PowerShell to v5.1 as Mathias suggested, which will resolve it right away.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! That solved the issue.